# Compare rows between two sheets - Function

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I think I’ve ‘over thought’ my problem so I’m starting from the beginning again.

I have two spreadsheets, one is an original database (org_DB) and the second is the updated database (new_DB). The number of rows is around 15,000 for org_DB and 18,000 for new_DB. The number of relevant contiguous columns is exactly 14 in both.

I need a third sheet, the results, that contains only the new_DB entries that are DIFFERENT from the original database, and, all new_DB entries that are ADDITIONAL.

The definition of DIFFERENT is a row with greater than 0 differences.

The definition of ADDITIONAL is a row that has no equivalence.

I think I need the two definitions because ‘new DB’ is longer than ‘org DB’ and all my formulas fail at the end point of org_DB.

The two test sized DB are:

**org_DB**

```
Code 1    Code 2    Code 3    Code 4
AA00001    AAGA    1180218        24
AA00007    AAGA    03821787-97    58
AA00008    AAGA    11821260-99    59
AA00009    AAGA    11001017       60
AA00016    AAGA    3801648        67
AA00017    AAGA    3801649       120
AA00018    AAGA    3801692        66
AA00019    AAGA    03821084-61    70
```

**new_DB**

```
Code 1    Code 2    Code 3    Code 4
AA00001    AAGA    1180218        24
AA00008    AAGA    11821260-99    59
AA00009    AAGA    11001015       60
AA00016    AAGA    3801648        67
AA00017    AAGA    3801649       120
AA00018    AAGA    3801692        69
AA00019    AAGA    03821084-61    70
XX00101    XXGA    1234X567X     101
XX00102    XXGB    1234X567X     101
```

**Result DB (the result I am looking for)**

```
AA00009    AAGA    11001015    60
AA00018    AAGA    3801692     69
XX00101    XXGA    1234X567X  101
XX00102    XXGB    1234X567X  101
```

For row comparison (which works on a row by row basis)  I’m using

```
=if(ArrayFormula(sum(--(new_DB!A2:D2=org_DB!A2:D2)))<>4,"Copy row","Ignore")
```

To get the result array I’m using

```
=filter(new_DB,if(ArrayFormula(sum(--(new_DB=org_DB)))<>4)
```

Problem 1 is that the FILTER condition argument only gets a single formula result from the ArrayFormula so fails with an #N/A - “FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: nn, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.”

Problem 2 is that the ArrayFormula after IF is comparing 1 row and nn columns - which I want. Wrapping the whole function in another ArrayFormula gives even stranger results.

Problem 3. Changing the row comparison function from IF ArrayFormula to SUMPRODUCT produces the wrong result when used in a ArrayFormula wrapper.

I can see that if that if I use this method then the recursion process is likely to be very lengthy - so I've come to accept my method is fundamentally flawed. Should I use a VLOOKUP and FILTER combo for column A. Column A is actually a SKU ID so should always be unique.

Can anyone help please. TIA

Note that org_DB row 3 (AA0007...) is not in the results. Deliberate.

Test sheet here: [Test DB Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GGo5RO5I6-HQmBsSNzYBfiFp7wOJiQFkAC66qRKK2I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The definitions of DIFFERENT and ADDITIONAL looks to be equivalent. Please provide examples of rows that meet each definition.

Comment: Is there any single column or some combination of columns less than all 14 that is a [primary key](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5547/primary-key)?

Comment: Also, shouldn't AA00017 appear as well as Code 4 changed?

Comment: @Ruben Indeed, they are the same but in my turmoil I always seemed to have to add an extra condition that accommodate non existence in the org_DB

Comment: @Robin Gertenbach Yes, column A is or should be unique SKU numbers. I just wanted to catch everything as I felt it was easier to De-duplicate/highlight as a second pass. Using FILTER and ArrrayFormula seemed to catch everything whereas VLOOKUP only catches the first instance.

Comment: @Ruben The examples are in result_DB where the first two exist on non-matching columns and the last two are additional rows not found in org_DB.

Comment: Could you use =query instead? The problem with this is that the query iteslf is not dynamic in that if you add a column in the sheet you are querying, it breaks the formula. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: @Karl_S  I seem to recall I did end up using QUERY but with REGEXMATCH as the key function. I'm afraid it was a long time ago now and many functions later on different projects so I don't have immediate access to my final solution. However, if any requests are left after this post I'll put in the effort to help others out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will look really ugly really quickly with a lot of columns which is why I'm asking of you have any columns you can limit yourself to.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(
  'New DB'!A2:D10,
  ISERROR(MATCH('New DB'!A2:A10 & "|" & 
                'New DB'!B2:B10 & "|" &
                'New DB'!C2:C10 & "|" &
                'New DB'!D2:D10, 
                'Org DB'!$A$2:$A$9 & "|" & 
                'Org DB'!$B$2:$B$9 & "|" &
                'Org DB'!$C$2:$C$9 & "|" & 
                'Org DB'!$D$2:$D$9,
                0))))
```

This filters the content of New DB by whether the concatenated columns of New DB can be found in Org DB, you can use any other Delimiter if you have | in there.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Robin - Limiting the test columns, yes. The resulting array needs all columns so I'll test your answer with the full array passed to FILTER yes?

Comment: Yes, I just used your sample data, you'll use all 14 columns